# How to change color of the <DropdownList> (from react-widgets) placeholder text?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, colors, dropdown, react-with-styles

```
                <DropdownList
                  data={baseYearDropdownOptions}
                  containerClassName={classNames(styles.dropDownList,           
                     'custom-react-dropdown')} 
                />

            

                .dropDownList
                 {
                   color: black;
                  }
```

Color of the text in dropdown placeholder is not changing ..

Comment: Can you inspect the page and see the dropdownlist element CSS name?

Comment: Yeah I did and tried adding the class for that element. But it did not work

Comment: If my understanding is correct then you want to change the color of all placeholders. Check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9rb4cs?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: I am using React.js with Nextjs ..I already tried in that way.did not work